# Wrapping Divs Just like in Windows Phone Grid Selector

Tags: css, html

I want to make square divs in HTML 5, like in the picture.

[image: WP Grid Selector]

This is my HTML5 Code - what should be in the CSS file so it can be just like in the picture ?

**(If it's possible in Bootstrap, please give me the classes needed for it instead of CSS Code)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    ....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```css
.container{
  width:200px;
}

.square{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  float :left;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.square {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.container {
   width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Something like this should do the trick:

```
.container{width:330px;}
.square{float:left; width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;}
```